# Cannot read property 'join' of undefined in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
client.on('message', message => {

    if(message.content === ('-join')){

        message.member.voiceChannel.join()
            .then(connection => console.log('Connected!'))
            .catch(console.error);

    }
});
```

The error is: "Cannot read property 'join' of undefined" and I don't know how to fix it. I've importet discord.js and discord.js-commando.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Read the docs - `message.member` is a GuildMember, which doesn't have a `voiceChannel` property. You may find the correct way to join a member's voice channel in the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Comment: "Cannot read property 'join' of undefined" means that "voiceChannel" is not an array and for that reason the method join does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the latest version of `discord.js` which is v12.

If that is the case, you can't access a GuildMember's voice channel using `message.member.voiceChannel` anymore so you'd need to use `message.member.voice.channel.join()` instead

Answer (score 0):

since [discord.js 12.0.0](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/12.0.0), the API uses a cache. Try that:

```
let channel_info = message.member.guild.voiceStates.cache.find(user => user.id == message.author.id)
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id == channel_info.channelID).join()
    .then(connection => console.log('Connected!'))
    .catch(console.error);
});
```